# Align table content

Tags: wordpress, html-table, alignment

I have a Wordpress site and I'm trying to align some text with an image using a table.

For some reason the image appears higher than the text on my site

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

The page is here:
http://pictureperfect.kpwebservices.net/about/

This is my code:

```
<table style="width: 86%;" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="50%"></td>
<td width="50%"></td>a
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Our aim is to ensure you look and feel your best on your special day. Whether it is your Wedding day, formal, Deb, Spring Carnival, photography and any occasion in between.

Picture Perfect Makeup is a mobile service catering Melbourne, surrounding and outer suburbs. We will come to your doorstep for your own comfort.

Mary Kechichian- Professional Makeup Artist and Stylist. Completed Training in Melbourne CBD with Elite Makeup Academy in advance Makeup artistry and Hair stylist.

Amongst my travels and learning Completed training in New York specialising in airbrushing, tattoo coverage with Kett Cosmetics.</td>
<td><img alt="" src="http://pictureperfect.kpwebservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/936482_507067716023365_1908922291_n.jpg" width="439" height="392" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text has the CSS attribute `vertical-align: baseline`, which will cause the image next to it to line up with the base of the first row of text.

Try changing this to `vertical-align: top`.

If you use Firefox, you can quickly see this in action by using Tools -> Web Developer -> Inspector on your page and then clicking on the `td` with text in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a vertical align to make sure that no matter how much your height increases, the text in the left block remains on top. Use something like:

```
<tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Our aim is to ensure you look and feel your best on your special day. Whether it is your;Wedding day, formal, Deb, SpringCarnival, photography and any occasion in between.<p></p>
<p>Picture Perfect Makeup is a mobile service catering Melbourne, surrounding and outer suburbs. We will come to your doorstep for your own comfort.</p>
<p>Mary Kechichian- Professional Makeup Artist and Stylist. Completed Training in Melbourne CBD with Elite Makeup Academy in advance Makeup artistry and Hair stylist.</p>
<p>Amongst my travels and learning Completed training in New York specialising in airbrushing, tattoo coverage with Kett Cosmetics.</p></td>
<td class="odd"><img alt="" src="http://pictureperfect.kpwebservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/936482_507067716023365_1908922291_n.jpg" width="439" height="392"></td>
</tr>
```

The style is in-line, however you can easily insert into a class and point the class to this cell. I would also suggest you put a margin on the image or padding into the cell where the image is located so that it looks much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the table with this:

```
<div style="width: 86%; position:relative; margin:0 auto;">


<div style="width:50%; float: left;">Our aim is to ensure you look and feel your best on your special day. Whether it is your;Wedding day, formal, Deb, SpringCarnival, photography and any occasion in between.</p>
<p>Picture Perfect Makeup is a mobile service catering Melbourne, surrounding and outer suburbs. We will come to your doorstep for your own comfort.</p>
<p>Mary Kechichian- Professional Makeup Artist and Stylist. Completed Training in Melbourne CBD with Elite Makeup Academy in advance Makeup artistry and Hair stylist.</p>
<p>Amongst my travels and learning Completed training in New York specialising in airbrushing, tattoo coverage with Kett Cosmetics.</div>

<div style="width:50%; float:right;"><img alt="" src="http://pictureperfect.kpwebservices.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/936482_507067716023365_1908922291_n.jpg" style="width:100%; max-width:439px; height: auto;" /></div>

</div>
```

You should try to avoid using tables to layout your page and use them for, well tabular data.

Hope this helps